# Get value from local.properties and use it in .tag & .jsp file

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, tags, application.properties

I have a file "local.properties" where I need to put a string variable and I need to use it in a .tag and .jsp file. Where I need to put this variable is instead of x:

```
<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=x"
```

...

```
(window,document,'script','dLayer',x);
```

I need a function that get the value from properties. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem.

${jalosession.tenant.config.getParameter('variable.x')}